# How to evaluate a list within overlapping intervals?

Tags: python

I have a list of time values. 
For example: `time = [-1.9493, -1.9433, -1.911 , -1.8977, -1.8671]`

And the next code allows me to create a new list of lists, where each element has the time values included in a given interval, in this case the interval is 0.05 seconds and each step is 0.01 seconds.

```
window = 0.05
overlap = 0.04
bounds = np.arange(time[0], time[-1] + window, window-overlap)
result = [
    list(filter(lambda x: bounds[i] <= x <= bounds[i+1], time))
    for i in range(len(bounds)-1)
    ]
result
[[-1.9493,-1.9433],[],[],[-1.911],[],[-1.8977],[],[],[-1.8671],[],[],[],[]]
```

I would like to screen the list using an overlapping interval, where each interval is 0.05 seconds long but 0.04 are the last 0.04 seconds of the previous interval and just advancing 0.01 seconds. 
From this screen with overlapping intervals, I expect to get something like:

```
[[-1.9493,-1.9433,-1.911],[-1.911,-1.8977],[-1.911,,-1.8977],[-1.911,-1.8977],[-1.8977,-1.8671],[-1.8977,-1.8671],[-1.8977,-1.8671],[-1.8671].[-1.8671],[]]
```

Comment: Instead of `bounds[i+1]` use `bounds[i]+window` in your `filter`

Answer (score 0):

If you use something like:

```
import numpy as np

time = [-1.9493, -1.9433, -1.911 , -1.8977, -1.8671]

window = 0.05
overlap = 0.04
bounds = np.arange(time[0], time[-1] + window, window-overlap)
result = [
    list(filter(lambda x: y-overlap <= x <= y+(window-overlap), time))
       for y in bounds
    ]

print(result)
```

... this outputs:

```
[[-1.9493, -1.9433], [-1.9493, -1.9433], [-1.9493, -1.9433], [-1.9493, -1.9433, -1.911], [-1.9493, -1.9433, -1.911], [-1.911, -1.8977], [-1.911, -1.8977], [-1.911, -1.8977], [-1.8977, -1.8671], [-1.8977, -1.8671], [-1.8671], [-1.8671], [-1.8671], []]
```

(the first four sub-lists of this list are not in your model output, but they just depend on which value is chosen for the first element of the `bounds` vector).